# Online Overleaf Editor: Clicked the Submit Button by mistake

Tags: overleaf

By mistake I clicked on the "Submit" button provided in the overleaf editor. Now my document shows:

"Manuscript Submitted to ACM"

I have following questions:

1. What I have to do with my document, it was an incomplete document?
2. Will my document be leaked out now?
3. How can I remove the line "Manuscript Submitted to ACM" from my document?

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt suggests that the "Submit" button actually downloads the document to your computer, so that you can then submit it to ACM.  Is it possible that the document is in your Downloads folder?  If so, 1. and 2. are moot, and you just need to deal with 3.  Also, consider contacting Overleaf support (although they'll probably spot this before too long).

Comment: Thanks my friend for your prompt reply. I checked the download folder and also the default folder but I can't find any latest version of my document there. I have also sent a message to the Help--> Contact form. Zulfi.

Comment: This is a weird bounty, or do I just don't get it? :)

Comment: Hi there, I'm Tom from Overleaf Support. I'll make a more detailed answer tomorrow explaining things in a bit more detail. In short: If you only clicked the first step in Submit, nothing happens. If you wanna be sure, please get in touch at support@overleaf.com from the email address you use to log in your Overleaf account and I'll check the email address against the submission records. I hope this helps!

Comment: @yo' I was just wondering because the post seems to be more than 4 months old.

Comment: Ah I haven't noticed it's so old! I saw it on StackTeX twitter :) In that case, I'll simply make a canonical answer, the OP probably doesn't need quick intervention anymore :)

Comment: @yo' This is why I do not get the bounty :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It's possible to see who offered the bounty, and it doesn't make more sense to me. Still, I provided the answer; it probably makes sense for this to be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

If you accidentally submitted a paper via the Overleaf's Submit modal, there are three options:

- Accidental submissions to the Overleaf Gallery: Simply contact us via support@overleaf.com and as for the submission to be rejected. We're happy to assist with this.
- Accidental submissions to journals with direct submission: In these cases, the files are not with us anymore. You'll need to get in touch with the journal's Editorial Office and ask for the submission to be disregarded. It shouldn't be an issue.
- Accidental submissions when a ZIP file was provided to you: Nothing is needed. You were given the ZIP file yourself, it hasn't been sent to any 3rd party.

Comment: Why is this freaky button placed big in middle of important clickable links? clickbait?

Comment: Hi @1.. Apologies if the button feels intrusive. The submit modal is important to a lot of users, and also, there's at least two extra confirmation steps that should prevent accidental submissions. If you have any specific concerns, feel free to get in touch via support@overleaf.com to discuss this further.

Comment: I am concerned if my documents went to gallery. Why cant it be in side or somewhere pleasant.

Comment: Hi @1.. If this is the concern, you can also get in touch via support@overleaf.com -- if you do that from the email address you use to log in your Overleaf account, we can easily check whether there are any pending submissions and reject them. Apologies once more if you find the Submit button cumbersome. I have passed your feedback to our UX/Product team for consideration.

Comment: Is there a way to find if there are documents I submitted to gallery by myself?

Comment: For Gallery submissions, you receive a confirmation when the project is submitted, and another confirmation when it's accepted, or a message explaining why it was rejected.

Comment: message to email or somewhere else?

Comment: Is the message sent to my email or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, yes, the message would be sent to your Overleaf's primary email address.